# How to extract a field with Gson?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have this json code (it's a part of entire json-code):

```
{
  "numFound": 41, 
  "edges": [
    {
      "endLemmas": "albero", 
      "context": "/ctx/all", 
      "end": "/c/it/albero/v", 
      "features": [
        "/c/it/alberatura /r/ConceptuallyRelatedTo -", 
        "/c/it/alberatura - /c/it/albero/v", 
        "- /r/ConceptuallyRelatedTo /c/it/albero/v"
      ], 
      "license": "/l/CC/By-SA", 
      "start": "/c/it/alberatura", 
      "startLemmas": "alberatura", 
      "text": [
        "albero", 
        "alberatura"
      ], 
      "uri": "/a/[/r/ConceptuallyRelatedTo/,/c/it/alberatura/,/c/it/albero/v/]", 
      "weight": 1.0, 
      "dataset": "/d/conceptnet/5/combined-sa", 
      "sources": [
        "/and/[/s/rule/wiktionary_monolingual_definitions/,/s/web/en.wiktionary.org/]"
      ], 
      "score": 7.81056, 
      "rel": "/r/ConceptuallyRelatedTo", 
      "timestamp": "2013-09-12T16:30:04.157Z", 
      "nodes": [
        "/r/ConceptuallyRelatedTo", 
        "/c/it/albero/v", 
        "/c/it/alberatura"
      ], 
      "id": "/e/021aa72c7605d9d2000f0774a0bf9042699fa6ee", 
      "surfaceText": "[[alberatura]] ConceptuallyRelatedTo [[albero]]"
    },
```

How to do I extract the field "**features**" ?
I can extract some fields, like "context" or "end", but for "features" I can't! :(

My Java code:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

   URL url = new URL("http://conceptnet5.media.mit.edu/data/5.1/c/it/albero?get=context");
      HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
      conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

      String inputLine;

      GsonCNItem gsonCNObj = new Gson().fromJson(br, GsonCNItem.class);

      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        try{
          gsonCNObj.getCNThing(i);
        }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}      
      }
    }
```

My GsonCNItem class:

```
public class GsonCNItem {

  private String context;
  private String end;
  private List<GsonCNItem> edges;

  public List<GsonCNItem> getCNedges(){
    return edges;
  }

 public void getCNThing (int i){
    System.out.println(edges.get(i));
  }

  public String toString(){
    return String.format("Context: %s\nend: %s",context,end);    
  }
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: No variable defined for `features` in Class `GsonCNItem` may be you can use `String[] features`

Answer (score 1):

But your class for deserializing JSON is wrong, it should be as following:

```
public class MyJson {
    private long numFound;
    private ArrayList<GsonCNItem> edges;

    public ArrayList<GsonCNItem> getEdges(){
        return getEdges();
    }

    public class GsonCNItem{
        private String endLemmas;
        private String context;
        private String end;
        private ArrayList<String> features;
        ...
        private ArrayList<String> text;
        ...

        public ArrayList<String> getFeatures(){
            return features;
        }

        public ArrayList<String> getText(){
            return text;
        }

        public String toString(){
            return String.format("Context: %s\nend: %s",context,end);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable `List<String>` to your POGO class(GsonCNItem) to parse features array.

```
public class GsonCNItem {
    private String context;
    private String end;

    private List<String> features;

    //Setters and Getters
}
```